# Deploy user defined function in excel developed using c# and Excel Dna, it has got so may culture specific files and other dlls along with xll files

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wix3.11

I have developed a project to create user defined function in excel using c# and Excel Dna, it has got so many culture specific files and other dlls along with xll files. 
I have never done this before, i am using WIX3.1 for packaging this, but was not successful so far, Can any one help me with step by step procedure so that I can package this, so that these functions are made available across organisation

Answer (score 1):

There is a template project for using Wix to install and Excel-DNA add-in here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/WiXInstaller
That can serve as a starting point, and includes code for the custom action you need to install the .xll.

An alternative is to use the commercial [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) tool, and follow this detailed step-by-step guide for doing the .xll installation: https://jiripik.com/2017/02/25/use-advanced-installer-excel-dna-project/

Comment: Does this work with add-ins developed in VB as well?

Comment: Yes, the WiXInstaller template is a good one for Excel-DNA add-ins built with VB.NET too.